# Changing specific row in table from void

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a populated TableView where i would like to change the image. When I'm inside cellForRowAtIndexPath I can change it by using:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

But I cannot figure out how to do the same thing inside the void, I have tried:

```
[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0]].imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

But it doesn't change the image at all.

Thanks,
/DSDeniso

EDIT:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
_row = indexPath.row;
[self changeImage];
}

- (void)changeImage{
UITableViewCell * cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_row inSection:0]];
if(cell)
{
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

} else {
NSLog( @"why is cell null?  Did I set row properly?");
}
}
```

Comment: When I'm inside the void, I don't see or feel anything. From which *method* in your view controller are you trying to modify your image?

Comment: A custom one called changeImage :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the cell to the method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    _row = indexPath.row;
    [self changeImageForCell:cell];
    }

    - (void)changeImageForCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell{
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    }
```

Comment: the most easiest and sexiest :p

Comment: Thanks, but please see my and Michaels discussion below :-)

Comment: because the method cellForRowAtindex is not completed and the cell is not sent back/set to the tableview so when you ask in void method to  get it, it probably returns nil which is obvious because you are asking to get something which you haven't set.